# Cant Get Crouching To Work For My Platformer

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

cant get crouching to work, I press S once and it crouches, but pressing again makes the character smaller, any way to make it go back up when letting go of S

- `Crouch();` is in `void Update()`

Here is the code:

```
    public GameObject Player;

    void Crouch()
    {
        if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.S))
        {
            Player.transform.localScale -= new Vector3(0, 0.3f, 0);
        }
    }
```

Comment: I don't know where you calling the `Crouch()` function, but I think you should do it in `Update()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`-=` will subtract new value. In this case you can use condition here

```
if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.S))
        {
            Player.transform.localScale = new Vector3(1, 0.7f, 1);
        } else {
            Player.transform.localScale = new Vector3(1, 1, 1);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to invoke your `Crouch()` function in the `Update()` function in `MonoBehaviour`.